# Unable to use managed identity to read from Azure keyvault with Spring Cloud Azure

Tags: spring, spring-boot, azure, azure-keyvault

I am running a Spring boot 3 application using the Spring Cloud Azure dependencies to access an Azure keyvault.
I created a user-assigned managed identity and I granted it Get/List permissions for secrets and properties via an access policy for the keyvault.
When I start up my application which is deployed to a Azure kubernetes cluster in the same subscription as the keyvault, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.azure.identity.CredentialUnavailableException: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Connection to IMDS endpoint cannot be established.
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(Unknown Source)
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAppProviderSupplier.fetchTokenUsingAppTokenProvider(AcquireTokenByAppProviderSupplier.java:76)
        ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.azure.identity.CredentialUnavailableException: ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Connection to IMDS endpoint cannot be established.
        at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient.lambda$authenticateToIMDSEndpoint$57(IdentityClient.java:1139)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.call(MonoCallable.java:72)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:174)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4470)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4551)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.toFuture(Mono.java:5063)
        at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClientBase.lambda$getManagedIdentityConfidentialClient$3(IdentityClientBase.java:362)
        at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAppProviderSupplier.fetchTokenUsingAppTokenProvider(AcquireTokenByAppProviderSupplier.java:75)
        ... 7 common frames omitted
```

I will note that if I use a different managed identity, everything works fine.  So it appears to be a problem with the managed identity I created, but I don't know why.

For reference here is my spring boot configuration:

```
    azure:
      keyvault:
        secret:
          property-sources:
            -
              endpoint: https://our-amazing-vault.vault.azure.net/
              credential:
                client-id: xxxx
                managed-identity-enabled: true
              profile:
                tenant-id: xxxx
          property-source-enabled: true
          enabled: true
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the managed identity was not added to the virtual machine scale set (VMSS) for the kubernetes service my app was deployed to.